# CNAME : Azure DNS Name 4 dots - Shorten?

Tags: azure, azure-networking

**Problem Statement :**

1. **Working Scenario :** We have old azure classic VM with DNS name XXX.cloudapp.net, We have domain name and was using CNAME in registrat who is managing name servers. So it was working fine XXX.com was redirecting to  XXX.cloudapp.net
2. **Error Scenario :** we recently added another azure VM DNS name XXX.**centralindia.cloudapp.azure.com**, went to resistrator admin domain manager console and updated CNAME of XXX.com - > XXX.**centralindia.cloudapp.azure.com**

Now when we visit xxx.com ( waited for 24 hours for CNAME resolution etc ) we get error - Unable to connect

domain Manager support team told us that due to 4 dots in Record value(XXX.centralindia.cloudapp.azure.com), records are not resolving.

I suggest you, please minimize the record value and then try to add it.

**How to fix this solution?** Domain manager team is telling us that they will not allow url with 4 dots? What is the reason for this? 
2. Can we shorted url on Azure console?

Comment: You can have many sub domains, the limit is from the domain team. Why is little difficult to answer. If this is a service you a buying, perhaps change to a different one.

Comment: @Drifter104 - thanks for reply. yes that's what i did change service. I don't understand this 4 dots restriction but doesn't make sense to me